# uuid values to binary and back

Tags: php

I am using the following two functions to convert uuid to binary and back. However, the uuid value converted does not return  as old the value after converting to binary. what should I do or am I not understanding the concept here.

```
function uuid_to_bin($uuid){
    $bin_uuid = pack("H*", str_replace('-', '', $uuid));
    return $bin_uuid;
}

function bin_to_uuid($binid)
{
    $arr= unpack("H*", $binid);
    $string = $arr['1'];
    $string = preg_replace("/([0-9a-f]{8})([0-9a-f]{4})([0-9a-f]{4}) 
    ([0-9a-f]{4})([0-9a-f]{12})/", "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5", $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: You should use the popular, mature and actively maintained [ramsey/uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) package instead of rolling your own.

Comment: okay thanks.. thats what I wanted.

Comment: Actually your code works, maybe you've got some invalid one? https://3v4l.org/a769C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use https://github.com/ramsey/uuid, which is already implementing the conversions correctly.

See https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/blob/29fb62b48611761b4c0c4e8f4a428cad19c2b690/src/Codec/StringCodec.php#L61-L100